# My program closes as soon as it opens

Tags: c#

Whenever i try to launch this it just come up with these errors and the app doesn't run. why? and how can i fix it, is it my editor? (I'm using Microsoft visual studio)

- The thread 0x1688 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
- The thread 0x470 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
- The thread 0xc1c has exited with code 259 (0x103).
- The thread 0x26f0 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
- The thread 0x2708 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
- The program '[7956] ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Here is the code.

```
using System;

namespace Inputoftext
{
    class Program
    {
        string str;
        public void detail()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Multiplication Calculator.");
            Console.WriteLine("Number 1: ");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            int number;
            Int32.TryParse(input, out number);
            Console.WriteLine("Number 2: ");
            string inputa = Console.ReadLine();
            int number;
            Int32.TryParse(input, out number);
        }
        public void calculations()
        {
            return input * inputa;
        }
        public void display()
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(str);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
    class call
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Program r = new Program();
            r.detail();
            r.calculations();
            r.display();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

btw I am new to c# so dont make it to complicated and im open for suggestions to improve my code.

Comment: I'm guessing it's launching another project, mainly because `Console.WriteLine(str);` should give a compiler error; `str` is never given a value. Check the solution list on the right, right click your solution and click 'Set as startup project'

Comment: Int parse can throw exception, use trycatch

Comment: This code could never compile. Please post the real code that causes the problems you're seeing.

Comment: return input * inputa; - variables input and inputa are not within the scope of the calculations method. As @JohnSaunders correctly pointed out, this program should not even compile let alone run.

Comment: Here is all of the errors http://lesquishy.freewebhost.co.nz/Index.html

Comment: down voting a brand new programmer is bad karma

Comment: @AaronAnodide: I believe it was down voted because he did not even post the source code that he executed and hence there is no way for anyone to figure out why he is not getting the output he expects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fixed version of your program:

```
class Program
{
    int answer;
    int number;
    int numbera;    
    public void detail()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Multiplication Calculator.");    

        string input;

        Console.WriteLine("Number 1: ");
        input = Console.ReadLine();
        Int32.TryParse(input, out number);

        Console.WriteLine("Number 2: ");   
        input = Console.ReadLine();
        Int32.TryParse(input, out numbera);
    }
    public void calculations()
    {
        answer = number * numbera;
    }
    public void display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(answer);
    }
}
class call
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Program r = new Program();
        r.detail();
        r.calculations();
        r.display();
    }
}
```

You may study these differences to begin to understand what was wrong..

[image]

Comment: Thanks Dude! This really helps. Considering i stared on Sunday being able to compare helps a lot.

Answer (score -3):

Looks like you're a beginner.

First, make your second class (Program) static. Like

```
public static void detail()
```

Now, instead of doing

```
Int32.TryParse(input, out number);
```

Do this: Make the numbers stored as "public" at top of your Program class. Get rid of TryParse, you don't need it

Like

```
class Program
{
    public int number; // can be accessed by other functions/methods
    public int othernumber ; // can be accessed by other functions/methods
    public int sum;

    public void detail()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Multiplication Calculator.");
        Console.WriteLine("Number 1: ");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        number = int.Parse(input);
        Console.WriteLine("Number 2: ");
        string inputa = Console.ReadLine();
        othernumber = int.Parse(inputa);
    }
```

For the calculations() you are returning something, but it is void (meaning it doesn't return)

Do this:

```
    public void calculations()
    {
        sum = number * othernumber; // sum should be a global variable
    }
```

For display do:

```
    public void display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n"); // doing \n makes a new line (you'll see)
        Console.WriteLine(sum.toString()); // we need to make it a string like that
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

If you are still getting errors, make a new project. It might be a Visual Studio problem.

But do those things I told ya!

**@Aaron Anodide's answer was Ok, but when it comes to Console.WriteLine(answer); it will error because you are trying to write an int and not a string!!!!**

Comment: `Console.WriteLine()` handles an `int` parameter just fine. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/70x4wcx1(v=vs.110).aspx